# Magento product isSaleable based on country

Tags: checkout, cart

I'm working on a new webshop, which will be international orientated. The problem I have is, some products I sell are available for all countries, except for the Netherlands due to new laws and regulations. Ofcourse I can make a specific store view for the Netherlands, and not show those products. But still Dutch customers can go to another view and add those products in their cart.

I think I might need to check the selected coutry of delivery in the cart / checkout. And delete "forbidden" products from the cart. But how?

I hope someone can push me in the right direction.

Regards,

Wouter

Answer (score 1):

You could use an extension for complex shipping logic like [Webshopapps Productmatrix](http://www.webshopapps.com/eu/shipping/productmatrix-shipping-extension.html) (the best shipping extension that I know of, and very widely used) where you can set up rules for the shipping method for groups of products.

With the Webshopapps extension, you would create a "package id" for "non-netherlands products" and set up the rules such that there will be no shipping method available for delivery addresses in the Netherlands.

Answer (score 0):

checkout below extension provides similar functionality to restrict product display for certain country based on users GEO Location

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/country-specific-products.html